# Overriding a method with a sealed class/interface parameter in java

Tags: java, overriding, sealed-class, exhaustive

Given this java code:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // These are objects of the only 2 classes that implement Parent
        // `sealed` defines that there can't be any other classes that implement Parent
        Child1 child1 = new Child1();
        Child2 child2 = new Child2();
        // I can call myMethod(child1) and myMethod(child2) on myClass
        MyInterface myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.myMethod(child1);
        myClass.myMethod(child2);
        // I can also call myMethod(child1) and myMethod(child2) on myInterface
        MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
        myInterface.myMethod(child1);
        myInterface.myMethod(child2);
    }
}

sealed interface Parent {}
record Child1() implements Parent {}
record Child2() implements Parent {}

interface MyInterface {
    void myMethod(Parent parent);
}

// Why can't I override myMethod(Parent parent) with myMethod(Child1 child1) and myMethod(Child2 child2)?
// This should be exhaustive, since Parent is sealed and there can't be any other classes that implement Parent
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    //@Override
    public void myMethod(Child1 child1) {
        System.out.println("Child1");
    }

    //@Override
    public void myMethod(Child2 child2) {
        System.out.println("Child2");
    }

    // Why is this method needed after declaring the two methods above?
    @Override
    public void myMethod(Parent parent) {
        if (parent instanceof Child1) {
            myMethod((Child1) parent);
        } else if (parent instanceof Child2) {
            myMethod((Child2) parent);
        }
    }
}
```

(See also: https://gist.github.com/CC007/768973376ce4ebbfdd3482c5f1bf90b9)

Why can't I override a method with a sealed type (class/interface) as one of the parameters (see `MyInterface`), by creating methods for the individual children of the sealed type? (see `MyClass`).

If the `Parent` interface wasn't sealed, I would understand that this implementation wouldn't guarantee to be exhaustive, but as a sealed type, there can't be any other child classes/records other than `Child1` and `Child2`.

So why can't I omit the `myMethod(Parent parent)` method in `MyClass` and why can't I define `@Override` on the other 2 methods in `MyClass`?

Comment: The interface say that you must have the method `myMethod(Parent parent)` so that at other locations, where the type `MyInterface` is used, the method `myMethod(Parent)` can be called. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have a reference of type `Parent`, you need a `myMethod(Parent)` to call. A `myMethod(Child1)` won't do, even if the object's actual type is `Child1`.

Comment: @Progman "_What exactly are you trying to do_" – I think the idea is that, since `Parent` is `sealed`, all direct subclasses are known at compile-time. And the OP expects providing an overload of `myMethod` for each subclass should be enough for the compiler, because the compiler knows there's not another unknown type of `Parent` to handle. Similar to how you can have exhaustive `switch` expressions with a sealed class hierarchy. It would be technically possible, I believe, for the compiler to implicitly implement `myMethod(Parent)` with the if-else branches.

Comment: @Rik The answer is basically, "_Because the Java language developers have not implemented that_". Note Java typically tries to avoid too much "magic" in the language itself.

Comment: @Slaw I indeed was thinking of the similarity with `switch`. Regarding the magic, I was thinking about parameter widening as a counter example for when java does add the magic, but I checked this and while you can widen parameters, you still need to have the interface implemented without widening. I didn't know this. Now I do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why can't I override a method with a sealed type (class/interface) as one of the parameters (see `MyInterface`), by creating methods for the individual children of the sealed type? (see `MyClass`).

This is not the way Java works. According to the specification:

> 8.4.8.1. An instance method m<sub>C</sub> [...] overrides [...] another method m<sub>A</sub> [...], if all of the following are true: [...] The signature of m<sub>C</sub> is a subsignature (§8.4.2) [...].
>
> 8.4.2. Two methods [...] have the same signature if they have the same name, [...], and, [...] the same formal parameter types.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1

One example of how Java sealed types work related to your example is [pattern matching](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html). You could write `myMethod` as follows:

```java
@Override
public void myMethod(Parent parent) {
  switch (parent) {
    case Child1 c -> System.out.println("Child1");
    case Child2 c -> System.out.println("Child2");
    //exhaustive because of sealed type
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so java doesn't have this feature. Probably for a good reason. 
But if I really wanted such a feature, I'd have to create a new annotation, say `@SealedOverride` and have to create a compile-time annotation processor that would check if there is a method that's annotated with `@SealedOverride` for every sealed class extension. Once that's checked, I would be able to generate code for the method (with a body similar to the one you provided in your answer). Manifold might be able to help with that implementation I think.

Comment: Why two separate class hierarchies (Parent-Child and MyInterface-MyClass)? If you'd move `myMethod()` (without parameters) to the parent and child classes, `parent.myMethod()` would be [dynamically dispatched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) and lead to the desired polymorphism.

Comment: @Knight_Industries You're right, but that's besides the point. Sometimes you don't have the option to do that, because the Parent and Child come from a library or something. Also, sometimes you want to separate thise concerns, for instance, when the method acts on or requires the sealed class, but it's not a feature of that class itself. If the sealed class was a model/data class and MyClass was a service class, you don't want to mix those two, because it would lead to a tangled spaghetti mess.

Comment: These scenarios can be handled without another language feature: If you want to stay with OOP, patterns like [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) can help decouple/connect two class hierarchies, e.g. by wrapping Parent-Child1-Child2 with MyInterface-MyClass1-MyClass2 leading to a clean structure. Within the Data Oriented paradigm on the other hand, *independent* functions operate on structured, immutable data and pattern matching can help discern the various cases (but without a second hierarchy MyInterface-MyClass), also leading to a clean structure.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I override myMethod(Parent parent) with myMethod(Child1
> child1)

Because when you have a class that implements `MyInterface`, it must have the method `myMethod(Parent parent)` exactly this.

```java
MyInterface myInterface = new MyClass();
```

Java won't magically determine to cast a parent into Child1 or Child2 for you, to choose a suitable method, this functionality doesn't exist, but you can suggest it.

When you use `myInterface.myMethod(new Child1());` It's valid because Child1 implements `Parent` and `myMethod` can only access the methods defined in `Parent` unless you try a cast in the method body.